# Accessing external database using FMDB in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I have an external database file and i want to access the records from that file into my app. Following is the code I got from a link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_8_Application_using_Swift_and_FMDB . In the following code, it has been explained how to create a database. Please help me where should I put my external sqlite file in Xcode and how to access it via FMDB

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
            .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
                    "contacts.db")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if contactDB == nil {
            println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if contactDB.open() {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
            if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code to retrieve data from database using FMDB but I am unable to know how can I access my external database using FMDB. In this example the person has accessed the database which he has first created in viewDidLoad()

```
@IBAction func findContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    if contactDB.open() {
        let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text)'"

        let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
         withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if results?.next() == true {
            address.text = results?.stringForColumn("address")
            phone.text = results?.stringForColumn("phone")
            status.text = "Record Found"
        } else {
            status.text = "Record not found"
            address.text = ""
            phone.text = ""
        }
        contactDB.close()
    } else {
        println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set flags??

Comment: where and how to set flags?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting full answer that how to set the `FMDB` in `Swift`..

It is stepwise process..

1. Copy/paste the files from `fmdbmaster/src/fmdb` to your project.
2. Then you have to create bridging header `#import "FMDB.h"`
3. Further you have to set the flag As follows

   - Go to Project>Target > Build Settings> Compile sources
   - Here, You will find some files `.h` and  `.m`
   - set the flag `'-fno-objc-arc'` on three files named
     `FMDatabase.m`, `FMResultSet.m` & `FMDatabaseAdditions.m`
   - To set the flag you have to double click on the field front of the files in compile resources. That's it. Flags will be set.

Still any doubt you can ask me .